# linq to xml what do I have to do to bind to gridview?

Tags: xml, linq, gridview, dataset, linq-to-xml

How do I setup VSTUDIO in order to bind my linq to xml query results to gridview rather than writing to console?

```
namespace TestCFG
```

{
    class Program
    {
        public class XAxisCalib
        {

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {


                string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
                foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                    var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                                select new
                                {

                                    MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                                    MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                                };
                    foreach (var x in query)
                    {
                        foreach (var nextLevel in x.MaxChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                        }
                        foreach (var nextLevel in x.MinChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                        }



                        var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                                     select new
                                     {

                                         MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                                         MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                                     };


                        foreach (var y in query2)
                        {
                            foreach (var nextLevel in y.MaxChild)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                            }
                            foreach (var nextLevel in y.MinChild)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                            }

                            var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                                         select new
                                         {

                                             MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                                             MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                                         };

                            foreach (var z in query3)
                            {
                                foreach (var nextLevel in z.MaxChild)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                                }
                                foreach (var nextLevel in z.MinChild)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something such as

```
YourDataGrid.DataSource = query3.ToList();
```

`YourDataGrid` is a fictitious object that should be replaced with whatever name you give the DataGrid that you create in a Windows Form application or a WPF application (though this is more complex)

Comment: do I just use a console application? I get the error: YourDataGrid does not exist in current context.

Comment: @Casey no, you need to create a WinForms or WPF application and add a datagrid to the main window. Just create a new project - WinForms or WPF - and you'll get a blank window where you can drag a gridview (as well as any other component) from the toolbox.